# Meaning of a pound sign (#) on a Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

For the following Bloch sphere representation of a qubit, what does the highlighted symbol mean? I'm not sure if it means anything or it's just for showing that it's a sphere, not a circle.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just showing the three-dimensionality of the sphere. Most representations I've seen don't add that since the dotted ellipse already communicates the idea of a sphere. For example:

[image]